# How to post an array of objects with Chai Http

Tags: node.js, post, chai, hapi.js

I'm trying to post an array of object with [ChaiHttp](https://github.com/chaijs/chai-http) like this:

```
agent.post('route/to/api')
  .send( locations: [{lat: lat1, lon: lon1}, {lat: lat2, lon: lon2}])
  .end (err, res) -> console.log err, res
```

It returns an error as below:

> ```
>  TypeError: first argument must be a string or Buffer
> at ClientRequest.OutgoingMessage.end (_http_outgoing.js:524:11)
> at Test.Request.end (node_modules/superagent/lib/node/index.js:1020:9)
> at node_modules/chai-http/lib/request.js:251:12
> at Test.then (node_modules/chai-http/lib/request.js:250:21)
> ```
>
> events.js:141
>         throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
>         ^
>
> Error: incorrect header check   at Zlib._handle.onerror
>   (zlib.js:363:17)

I also tried to post like this, as we do with postman:

```
agent.post('route/to/api')
  .field( 'locations[0].lat', xxx)
  .field( 'locations[0].lan', xxx)
  .field( 'locations[1].lat', xxx)
  .field( 'locations[2].lat', xxx)
  .then (res) -> console.log res
```

but payload.locations is received as an undefined.

Any idea how to post an array of objects via chai-http?

**EDIT:**

Here is my route and I think there's something wrong with stream payload:

```
method: 'POST'
path:
config:
  handler: my_handler
  payload:
    output: 'stream'
```

Comment: @Cuthbert, no. `field` method accepts strings as second arg.
I used `JSON.stringify` instead and made my post. However I figured out the main issue is either superagent or payload output.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had the same problme here. It seems that simply the chai-http documentation is wrong. It sais:

```
// Send some Form Data
chai.request(app)
 .post('/user/me')
 .field('_method', 'put')
 .field('password', '123')
 .field('confirmPassword', '123')
```

Which does NOT work.   This worked for me:

```
chai.request(app)
  .post('/create')
  .send({ 
      title: 'Dummy title',
      description: 'Dummy description'
  })
  .end(function(err, res) { ... }
```

Comment: How does this answer the question ?

Comment: This does not answer the question and it is not even the correct way of doing it. What if you were sending files via multipart/formdata?

Answer (score 2):

Try to use `.send({locations: [{lat: lat1, lon: lon1}, {lat: lat2, lon: lon2}]})`. Because `.field('a', 'b')` not working.

1. `body` as a form data

   ```
   .put('/path/endpoint')
   .type('form')
   .send({foo: 'bar'})
   // .field('foo' , 'bar')
   .end(function(err, res) {}

   // headers received, set by the plugin apparently
   'accept-encoding': 'gzip, deflate',
   'user-agent': 'node-superagent/2.3.0',
   'content-type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
   'content-length': '127',
   ```
2. `body` as `application/json`

   ```
   .put('/path/endpoint')
   .set('content-type', 'application/json')
   .send({foo: 'bar'})
   // .field('foo' , 'bar')
   .end(function(err, res) {}

   // headers received, set by the plugin apparently
   'accept-encoding': 'gzip, deflate',
   'user-agent': 'node-superagent/2.3.0',
   'content-type': 'application/json',
   'content-length': '105',
   ```

Answer (score 0):

Faced the same problem and my solution was not to use a JSON Object for the send method but rather a raw string:

```
    chai.request(uri)
        .post("/auth")
        .set('content-type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded')
        .send(`Login[Username]=${validUser1.username}`)
        .send(`Login[Password]=${validUser1.password}`)
        .send(`RememberMe=false`)
        .end((err, res) => {
            res.should.have.status(200);
            // ...
        });
```